# Prisma multiple schema with the same model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, schema, prisma

Can I create a prisma model that is in 2 diferite schema but the model is the same? It will be very helpful to know if is a way to do that but till now I didn’t find a way to do that

```
Model Schema1.User{
} 
      
Model Schema2.User{
} 
Model User {
@schema(“schema1”,”schema2”)
}
```